# egrep results to vim as a line referenced filelist

Tags: bash, shell, vim, grep

In a shell I use the following function to create a filelist and pass it to vim.

Feels alright, but I lost the line reference, I open the files in correct order but then I have to search again for the text as the cursor starts at first line.

Actual function on ~/.bashrc

```
function vimgrep(){
   vim `grep -IR "$1" * | awk -F: '$1!=f{print ""$1"";f=$1}' | grep -v 'Test\|test'` +ls
}

function vimgrep2(){
   vim `grep -IR "$1" * | awk -F: '$1!=f{print ""$1"";f=$1}' ` +ls
}
```

Obs.: filelist must come from shell to vim, and then it must keep the line reference of the buffered files, just like with the results of :make when it catches any error (but without the bottom window [:cwindow]).

edited:
Ok... not so elegant, but I could pass the searched string to vim as +/"$1", like:

```
   vim `grep -IR "$1" * | awk -F: '$1!=f{print ""$1"";f=$1}' ` +/"$1"
```

Would be better if the script doesn't use a temporary file.

Comment: A shoot in the dark but you could write the line addresses to a `list_of_lines` and start vim with `-q list_of_lines`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim also comes with a `vimgrep` command you could use

```
function vimgrep() {
    local regex="$1"

    if [[ -z "$regex" ]]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 regex" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi

    vim -c "vimgrep /$regex/ **"
}
```

Be careful of running it in a directory with a lot of files below it.

Comment: That works! Thanks, I only edited a little bit:
`vim -c "vimgrep /$regex/ **/*.h **/*.cpp"`

Comment: Strange but it doesn't accept the *****/****.{h,cpp} pattern, but that above works!

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Line Numbers with an External Grep

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to open more than one file at a time using the line number option flag because Vim will only apply the flag to the first file in the list. The man page says:

> ```
>  +[num]      For the first file the cursor will be positioned on line  
>              "num". If "num" is missing, the cursor will be positioned
>              on the last line.
> ```

So, you could call the function on each file one at a time, or put the function call in a loop that operates on two positional parameters (a file name and a regular expression) at a time. The former is certainly easier. For example:

```
vimgrep () {
    local file="$1"
    shift || return 1
    vim +$(egrep -n "$1" "$file" | cut -d: -f1) "$file"
}

# Sample function call.
vimgrep /etc/password '^www-data'
```

Comment: maybe one way is to set a mark m{a-zA-Z} on each line, but for this we would be over the "up to 10 cmd" that vim takes as arguments with -c ou +cmd.
Seems like this will end up with a temp golfy file script, created and deleted everytime vimgrep is called.

Comment: other is to load an buffer must like :make does when something goes wrong. Now I'm googling for -q options example.

Answer (score 1):

With this you can move between matches via `cn`, `cp`, `cc`.. ect:

```
function vimgrep(){
   vim -c "exec(\"grep $1 *\")"
}
```

With highlighting:

```
function vimgrep(){
   vim -c "exec(\"grep -IR $1 *\")" -c "let @/='$1'" -c "set hls"
}
```

Comment: @CodeGnome, you can select between matches in `visual mode` by pressing `n`.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer:* I know nothing about `vim`

The man page says with an argument like `+<line no>` it will jump to that line for the provided file. Based on this information I whipped up this script. It relies on a command line like the following to start vim:

```
$ vim +n1 file1 +n2 file2
```

You could also put it as a shell function in your `'~/.bashrc` as it is quite small.

**Usage:** `vimgrep -e <search pattern> <fileglob>`

The search pattern can be any regular expression understood by `grep`, and file glob is a shell glob understood by `bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set -o xtrace # uncomment to debug

# declare variables
declare -a grepopts files

[[ $1 =~ -e$ ]] && grepopts+=("-e") && grepopts+=("$2") && shift 2

files=("${@}")

vim $(egrep -n -m1 -H "${grepopts[@]}" "${files[@]}" | \
        sed -e 's/^\(.\+\):\([0-9]\+\):.\+$/+\2 \1/')
```

**Caveat:** This script will fail if the file name has a `:` character in it.

Comment: with that bashrc wouldn't the **Usage** be vim -e <pattern> <dropableAfterDoneFile> ?

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel Sorry, I don't follow your comment. My usage line was based on the fact that you named your example function `vimgrep` in the question. It should be what ever name you give to the script or the shell function; in bash variable terms: `$0 -e <pattern> <fileglob>`. PS: I just edited the answer with some more comments

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel Do you want the function/script to open all the files one at a time? As in, open file1 with match, you do something, :q, open file2 with match, do something, :q, and so on?

Comment: The files will be buffered in a list, which is accessable through :ls, just like when you do "vim text1.txt text2.txt", when :ls inside vim is executed it appears a list with the buffered files, vim will start with the first file of the list then you can navigate with :next, but when we do that the cursor always go to the line 1, not for the grep line (where the pattern was matched).

Comment: I don't know how, but when you do :make, and there results in error, vim can hold a reference to file + line, where you can navigate through :cnext :cp :cwindow

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel Okay, I think I see what you mean. The script in my answer does exactly that for Emacs but doesn't quite work for vim when there are more than 1 file. A work around might be what I asked in my second comment; open file1, do stuff, quit, open file2, do stuff, quit and so on. If you think that is acceptable, I can change the script accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, the best of having a list of files is that you can do something like :argdo %s/AaA/aaa/g | update and make the substitution for all the files. Or simply :wa to write them all.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some functions that provide you with exactly what you want. It will open each file in a buffer with the line set to the first line that matches your given regex.

I tend to prefer short descriptive bash functions like this, since bash is hard enough to understand without using massive blocks of code.

The only flaw with this is that it doesn't filter out binary files effectively. An update to the `find_nonbinary` function will fix this.

**These are helper functions. They are not to be run directly.**

```
# Using print0 to handle files with weird names.
# This is just a quick placeholder.
# You can play with this to get better results.
function __find_nonbinary() {
    find -type f -print0
}

function __generate_vim_cmds() {
    xargs -0 awk -v regex="$regex" \
        '$0 ~ regex {printf "e +%s %s\n", FNR, FILENAME; nextfile}'
}

function __combine_vim_cmds() {
    declare -a vim_cmds

    while read line; do
        vim_cmds+=( " $line " )
    done

    # Force subshell to prevent IFS from being clobbered.
    (
        IFS="|"
        echo "${vim_cmds[*]}"
    )
}
```

This is the actual function to use.

```
function vimgrep() {
    local regex="$1"

    if [[ -z "$regex" ]]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 regex" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi

    local vim_cmds=$(
        __find_nonbinary    |
        __generate_vim_cmds |
        __combine_vim_cmds
    )

    if [[ -z "$vim_cmds" ]]; then
        echo "No files matching $regex found." 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi

    vim -c "$vim_cmds"
}
```

Comment: the find results in: ./TestMaxFoo./foo./TestFooMessage./Test<goes on>, at the end my ps1 is appears in the same line <...at the end of the result>./TestFooCenter.o./TestFooMetrics.o

Comment: With the second cmd the result is:
e +1 ./TestMaxFooSize<LF>
e +1 ./foo<LF>
e +1 ./TestFooMessage <etc>

Comment: @Rodrigo: You're not supposed to run the functions manually. They're used in the vimgrep function below.

Comment: I did it for debug purposes =D, for you to see what happened